# What is this secondary transition in the simulation of the Ising model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, ising-model

[image: Plot of average spin]
Here, the horizontal axis is the strength of the ambient magnetic field. The Hamiltonian I used is $$H = -h\sum_i \sigma_i - J\sum_{\langle i \, j \rangle}\sigma_i\sigma_j.$$ The horizontal axis is $h$, and the vertical axis is the average of the spin values $\sigma_i\in\{\pm1\}$. $J$ is set to $1$ for simplicity. For low temperatures ($\beta$ is $3$, $5$, $7$ for blue, red, green respectively), apart from the expected phase transition at $h=0$, there is two other 'steps' appearing on both sides of the plot. The asymptotic value seems to be about 0.65, not very reasonable for any explanations I can think of: fluctuations from the last round of Markov spin-flipping (only 100 is candidate to be flipped each round, out of 10000), the external field has quenched most flipping (the average should have been $\pm 1$, then), etc.

Is this phenomenon caused by computational flaws, or is it actually appearing in the physic model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the used value for the coupling constant $J$?

Comment: @WarreG edited. $J=1$.

Comment: +1, this is a very good question. Have you tried varying the time for which you run the simulation? It could be that this is a transition in kinetic rates, not just the equilibrium state.

Comment: Though, at low temperatures you should have average spin values of +1 or -1, so there is something strange here in any case. You may have a bug. Have you tried watching your simulation graphically?

Comment: Not sure if it has any influence but, what is the dimensionality of your system? How much neighbors does each spin have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to @Nathaniel the problem is solved. The asymptotic value actually varies according to the simulation time. So this is because the system has not yet reached a stable state. The simulation time was chosen because, since I didn't want to wait for too long, the algorithm has to stop in a reasonable amount of time. After lengthening the simulation time, I got a perfect one-step curve.

Having come to this, one can further conclude that, when running Monte-Carlo type algorithms, it is quite important to check for convergence. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And convergence of MC algorithms is quite slow, O($\sqrt{n}$) ($n$ is number of samples)! The life of a computationalist... good results are not easy/cheap/fast results.